# Linux directory conventions for custom service

Tags: linux, directory, daemon

I'm writing a custom application that will be run as a service/daemon. According to convention, the binaries for it should be in `/opt/appname`. However, where do I put files such as:

- Config files
- Cache and storage
- Logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `/opt/<appname>` for your app then config files go under `/etc/opt`, and the rest goes under `/var/opt`.

[source](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.pdf) which youd tell you what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you don't care where it's installed, and you can configure the app at build or install time. If, for example, you're building an application that will run on Debian, you can create a .deb package and skip this entire question.

Comment: Sure, the server admin can configure the app any way he wants, but that's precisely what I have to do, to not only develop but also install the app.